# Use C# to ZIP a Word docx

Tags: c#, excel, file, ms-word, zip

I have a Word document (.docx) that has a lot of embedded Excel worksheets in it. I'd like to be able to zip the .docx so that I can use the word > embeddings folder of the zip file to access the individual Excel worksheets.

Any help? Is it as simple as writing code to rename the file to a .zip? I've looked into the C# ZipPackage but it's not as straightforward as I figured.

Answer (score 1):

A `.docx` file is a Zip file already as you know, and the contents inside of it can be manipulated using the [Open XML SDK for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) (recommended).

- GitHub repo: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK
- NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/

---

You can, of course, use any library that can read/write zip files to read the contents, parse the XML files inside, and manipulate them yourself directly, with the risk of corrupting the file if you make a mistake writing to it.